# Image removed but still using network traffic

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a strange problem here, and i can't find any usefull results using google search, so I now ask for your help.

I have a video stream on my HTML+Javascript(mostly jQuery) application.
It is embeded like this:

```
<img width='300' id='videoFeedImg' src='http://IP:PORT/PAGE' />
```

Where this PAGE is acutally a live updating stream of pictures.

It works great!

But the problem is, that it is used on a page where it only has to be displayed when the user clicks a button. This is no problem, I just create this image shown above with the append() function in jQuery.
When the button is clicked, it is created and it is shown in the Inspection tool under Network (and it is easy to see in the Task manager Nerworking page to), and is making pretty huge network traffic.

But no matter what i do, i can't kill this stream/bandwidth. I tried to:
1. replace src with someting else
2. remove the picture
3. detach everthing i attached
4. use all kinds of jQuery functions like .stop() on the image and .empty() and .html(""); on the parent .

The only thing that works is this:

```
if (window.stop !== undefined) {
    window.stop();
}
else if (document.execCommand !== undefined) {
    document.execCommand("Stop", false);
}
```

But it is kind of drastic (maybe not??)

Does anybody have any good idears on how to stop this from loading/downloading?

Best regards
Bjarke

Comment: If src is set then the images will start downloading before any script can clear it/them.  Leave the images with no src in the html (or whatever format the page is) and then set it with jQuery if needed.  That way there's nothing for the images to download.

Comment: This the stream of images being loaded via some other script, maybe a jquery plugin?  If so checkout its documentation. I'm afraid that without more information I can't really say what's going on.

Comment: Archer: thanks for your reply. But the img is made by jQuery on the fly, and is not really an image, but a live stream of images, that wont stop streaming, even after element is killed, src is changed, it is deatached etc.

Comment: @Archer, unfortunately I don't think this will work in the OP's case. I believe his server-side script is leaving the connection open and constantly "pushing" new frames. Edit: damn! too slow!

Comment: @Bjarkes, the code you currently have is the best (only?) thing you can do to achieve what you want in your case.

Comment: @Bjarkes - as said by Robert then, we can't really help without knowing how the stream of images is being pulled.  If you're using a common library then maybe someone here has experience and can point you at a stop type of function.

Comment: @Archer, a note and a question. When the `src` was added AFTER the page has already loaded then a request to get the image will be made. Let's say it's a big image and in the middle of the loading you removed the whole `img` element from the DOM, will the connection be aborted? (normal static image)

Comment: @Adnan AFAIK, no - once the image has started downloading then it will continue to download.  That's not what's happening here though.  It's a control that loads multiple images and is continuing to work, despite removing the image.  It just needs to be told to stop, somehow, which is why I asked what library (if any) the OP is using.

Comment: @Archer, I might be wrong but I don't think that's the case here. I think he has something like this http://webcamera2.vaasa.fi:82/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi

Comment: @Adnan - I think it's best we don't try to second-guess what the OP is using.  They'll respond and then we can help them in an informed manner.

Comment: Thank you for you inputs! You are surely fast :) We use this: http://www.ros.org/wiki/mjpeg_server

Comment: The reason for the use of this maybe not wellknown package, is that we are streaming from a robot, using the Robot Operation System (ROS).